Typescript Curry Function with generic functions
Below is a typescript curry function definition from a medium.com article that's pretty neat. I was wondering if it would be at all possible to create a typescript curry function like this that allows for a function with generics. Or at least a way to create a curry function where you can more or less specify a custom return type.
E.g.
const example_curry = curry(<T>(name: string, int: number): Promise<T> => {...});
const named_curry = example_curry('name');
const curry_result = named_curry<string>(5);

/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
// curry utilty type from https://medium.com/codex/currying-in-typescript-ca5226c85b85

type PartialTuple<
  TUPLE extends any[],
  EXTRACTED extends any[] = []
> = TUPLE extends [infer NEXT_PARAM, ...(infer REMAINING)]
  ? PartialTuple<REMAINING, [...EXTRACTED, NEXT_PARAM?]>
  : [...EXTRACTED, ...TUPLE];

type PartialParameters<FN extends (...args: any[]) => any> = PartialTuple<
  Parameters<FN>
>;

type RemainingParameters<
  PROVIDED extends any[],
  EXPECTED extends any[]
> = EXPECTED extends [infer E1, ...(infer EX)]
  ? PROVIDED extends [infer P1, ...(infer PX)]
    ? P1 extends E1
      ? RemainingParameters<PX, EX>
      : never
    : EXPECTED
  : [];

type CurriedFunction<
  PROVIDED extends any[],
  FN extends (...args: any[]) => any
> = <
  NEW_ARGS extends PartialTuple<RemainingParameters<PROVIDED, Parameters<FN>>>
>(
  ...args: NEW_ARGS
) => CurriedFunctionOrReturnValue<[...PROVIDED, ...NEW_ARGS], FN>;

type CurriedFunctionOrReturnValue<
  PROVIDED extends any[],
  FN extends (...args: any[]) => any
> = RemainingParameters<PROVIDED, Parameters<FN>> extends [any, ...any[]]
  ? CurriedFunction<PROVIDED, FN>
  : ReturnType<FN>;

export default function curry<
  FN extends (...args: any[]) => any,
  STARTING_ARGS extends PartialParameters<FN>
>(
  targetFn: FN,
  ...existingArgs: STARTING_ARGS
): CurriedFunction<STARTING_ARGS, FN> {
  return function(...args) {
    const totalArgs = [...existingArgs, ...args];
    if (totalArgs.length >= targetFn.length) {
      return targetFn(...totalArgs);
    }
    return curry(targetFn, ...(totalArgs as PartialParameters<FN>));
  };
}

I've tried rewrites of the definition with a generic value for the return, or having curry return something like function<T>, but in the end I was just guessing and checking as I don't really know enough about the underlying TS machinery to more intelligently tackle this. Thanks for your time!

Welcome to Stack Overflow. That utility type is very complicated; this might need a complete rewrite if it's even possible; can you just provide some use cases (expected input/output types) and how they should act so that we have code to test against? I'm not even sure what a curried version of <T>(name: string, int: number): Promise<T> even looks like. Where should the T generic be scoped?  Would it be (approximately) <T>(name: string) => (int: number) => Promise<T>? Or (name: string) => <T>(int: number) => Promise<T>? Why is T even there if it's unused in the parameters?

(see prev comment) Actually, from poking at this, I'd say it's impossible no matter the details of what you want. TS's support for transforming generic functions is limited to that introduced in TS3.4 which only works in limited circumstances. Pulling apart parameter lists breaks it. The closest I can get to the simplest curry looks like this. Still, please [edit] to make your needs clear so the answer can give the (presumably) bad news.

To be honest I did not completely read the question but I guess you want to curry a function and preserve its generics.
Here is what you can do:
type CurryOverload = {
  <A, R>(cb: (p1: A) => R): (p1: A) => R;
  <A, B, R>(cb: (p1: A, p2: B) => R): (p1: A) => (p2: B) => R;
  <A, B, C, R>(cb: (p1: A, p2: B, p3: C) => R): (p1: A) => (p2: B) => (p3: C) => R;
  // todo: add more later
};

const curry: CurryOverload = (() => {}) as any;

const result = curry(<N>(name: N, age: number) => name); // => const result: <N>(p1: N) => (p2: number) => N


If you want a custom return type then you can introduce a generic to the overload.
